# UITableViewCell not updating properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've created a custom UITableViewCell but am having trouble updating the contents of the cell. When I have multiple cells in the table, the table is not drawing the correct images in the cell. The images in each cell should be unique, however I am seeing different cells with the same image. The table seems to be placing the cells at random.

I've checked my data source with NSLog and the names are correct. I can correct the issue when I don't use `- (UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`, but instead create a new cell each time in `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Any suggestion on what I may be doing wrong? Please have a look at my code below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ScoreCell *cell = (ScoreCell *)[_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellID"];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[ScoreCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellID"] autorelease];
    }

    BoxScore *boxScore = [_gameDayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setScoreImage:[UIImage imageNamed:boxScore.name]];

    return cell;
}
```

ScoreCell.h

```
@interface ScoreCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UIImage *scoreImage;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImage *scoreImage;

@end
```

ScoreCell.m

```
@implementation ScoreCell

@synthesize scoreImage;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [scoreImage release], scoreImage = nil;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [scoreImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(5,5)];
}

@end
```

Comment: the class names don't jive - i hope that's an artifact of posting snippits here

Comment: Thanks, it was an artifact. Fixed.

Comment: the apparent randomness is not likely random - when a cell scrolls out of view it gets reused.  one is scrolling on from the other side, if the state doesn't get correctly reset by your code you get the behavior you're seeing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two non-related problems with your image handling.
Scrolling off and on the screen will cause a cell to load the image twice (or a hundred times, depending on the user).

You want a

```
- (UIImage *)boxScoreImageForIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

method to (lazy) load, hold on to, and provide the image for the cell.

You also don't want to use `imageNamed:`, in your case it will cause twice as much memory usage than needed.  Use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead.

Comment: For some reason, `imageWithContentsOfFile:` worked and `imageNamed:` did not. I also added `[cell setNeedsDisplay]`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other comments, be sure to implement the `-prepareForReuse` method in your `ScoreCell` class. It gets called when the cell is to be reused, at which point you should clear the image. Be sure to call `[super prepareForReuse];` in your implementation. This will prevent the cell from being reused with the wrong image.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think `prepareForReuse` is a much better place to put `setNeedsDisplay`, which forces the cell to redraw it's content.

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearing the previous image. When a cell is dequeued it is not dealloced.

So sometimes the image that was drawn on the cell the times before it show through in front of the new image.

In drawRect you need to clear everything.

Either do:

```
CGContextClearRect( context , [self bounds] );
```

Or set `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` on the cell when it is created.

Comment: `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` is set to yes by default. I'm not too sure about `CGContextClearRect`.